# Postgres join when only one row is equal

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables and I am wanting to do an inner join between `table_1` and `table_2` but only when there is one row in `table_2` that meets the join criteria.

For example:

`table_1`

```
 id              | name             | age          |           
-----------------+------------------+--------------+  
 1               | john jones       | 10           |
 2               | pete smith       | 15           | 
 3               | mary lewis       | 12           | 
 4               | amy roberts      | 13           |
```

`table_2`

```
 id              | name             | age          | hair         | height       |           
-----------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
 1               | john jones       | 10           | brown        | 100          |
 2               | john jones       | 10           | blonde       | 132          | 
 3               | mary lewis       | 12           | brown        | 146          | 
 4               | pete smith       | 15           | black        | 171          |
```

So I want to do a join when name is equal, but only when there is one corresponding matching name in `table_2`

So my results would look like this:

```
 id              | name             | age          |  hair        |        
-----------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+  
 2               | pete smith       | 15           | black        | 
 3               | mary lewis       | 12           | brown        |
```

As you can see, John Jones isn't in the results as there are two corresponding rows in `table_2`.

My initial code looks like this:

```
select tb.id,tb.name,tb.age,sc.hair
from table_1 tb
inner join table_2 sc
on tb.name = sc.name and tb.age = sc.age
```

Can I apply a clause within the join so that it only joins on rows which are unique matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by all columns and apply `having count(*) = 1`

```
select tb.id,tb.name,tb.age,sc.hair
from table_1 tb
join table_2 sc
  on tb.name = sc.name and tb.age = sc.age
group by tb.id,tb.name,tb.age,sc.hair
having count(*) = 1
```

The interesting thing to note is that you don’t need the aggregate expression (in the case `count(*)` )in the `select` clause.